# Using Flex to display single rasters from raster catalog in ArcSDE/ArcGIS server?

Tags: raster, arcgis-server, enterprise-geodatabase, arcgis-flex-api, raster-catalog

One of the front end develoeprs here is having issues displaying, or working out how to display a single raster held in a raster catalog in ArcSDE using the Flex 2.2 API

the Raster Catalog holds about 30 images and he wants to search for one of these images, based on either the name of the raster, or some attribution tied to each raster, but can't figure out how.

Has anyone done this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We did this by simply adding search parameters to the layerDefinitions of the dynamic map service holding the rasters and features in a search function called on load.

Answer (score 1):

If you publish your raster catalog as an ImageService (not MapService) using ArcGIS Server 10, then you can query the raster catalog using the same Query/QueryTask that is used to query a layer inside a Map Service. (Note that in the case of a Map Service, you would point the QueryTask url to a layer within a MapService, but for an Image Service you use the url to the service itself.)

There is a sample that shows how to query the raster catalog of an Image Service layer:
http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/flex/samples/index.html?sample=QueryImageService

The REST documentation on ImageService might also be helpful - http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/apis/rest/index.html?imageserver.html

Comment: I thought about this, but do you not need additional licensing for Image services?

Comment: @Hairy :  I don't think you need special licensing to publish a basic Image Service (using ArcGIS Server 10.0 and later), but I'm not too familiar with the licensing aspect.

Comment: I may be nmaking the mistake that you cna actually display the contents of a rastercatalog in an image service, where the reality is, you cna only sue image services for tiled background rasters, and that to serve images up, per se, you need the image server and subsequent license.  I say this, as whenever I try to publish from an MXD, I get this error:

Comment: Unable to get raster data information 0x80041018 - Failed to open raster dataset in '"esriDataSourcesRaster.GdalRasterDataset"'

Comment: and if I try to add them direct from teh database, they don't appear?  I am a touch confused...

Comment: OK, you cannot use RasterCatalogs in Image services, so they have to be map services.  Now I have explained to the front end developer, he can query the rastercatalog for the raster details, but we're unsure, with the flex api, how to display the raster therein.  I guess my end, the back end, is functioning fine and it should be resolved using a map service, not image service, but me and the front end chap need to find out how to display returned rasters form the queries.  Thanks for all the advice.

Comment: @Hairy, do you have a public service?  What version of ArcGIS Server are you using?

Comment: ArcGIS 10 SP1  It is all sorted now, so we're fine, but I think there are issues working from Server 10, to 9.3 SDE and the like.  I also think the FLEX API is new to the front end developer, so he's learning on the fly as such.  Thanks for all your help.